# Ruby regex replace text, except text inside delimiter

Tags: regex, ruby

I would like to use Ruby's `gsub` to replace text except those inside a specific delimiter, like this:

```
regex = /(.+?)(@.+?@)(.+?)/
text = "aaa@xxx@bbb aaa@xxx@bbb"
text.gsub(regex){"#{$1.upcase}#{$2}#{$3.upcase}"}
```

I would like the return value to be `AAA@xxx@BBB AAA@xxx@BBB`, but it is `AAA@xxx@BBB AAA@xxx@Bbb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
regex = /(?:@.*?@|@|\G)\K[^@]+/
text = "aaa@xxx@bbb aaa@bbb"
puts text.gsub(regex, &:upcase)
```

Prints:

```
AAA@xxx@BBB AAA@BBB
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dxb8Vj/1)

---

- `(?:@.*?@|@|\G)` - Non-capture group to match either `@` to the nearest `@` or a single `@` or match at the end of previous reported match;
- `\K[^@]+` - Reset match and then capture 1+ characters other than `@`.

Comment: It won't work if `text = "aaa@xxx@bbb aaa@bbb"`

Comment: @Starscream512 What is the desired output in case of unbalanced `@` characters?

Comment: Desired output if `text = "aaa@xxx@bbb aaa@bbb"` is `AAA@xxx@BBB AAA@BBB`, since an unbalanced `@` doesn't count as a delimiter.

Comment: @Starscream512 so what makes that the 1st @ is the 1st delimiter and not the 2nd to the third? Is it the space? Is it the order they appear in?

Comment: It's the order that they appear in.

Comment: @Starscream512, see edit.

Comment: It doesn't work if `text = "@xxx@"`.

Comment: Then change the last quantifier to `*` @Starscream512

Comment: Ok, I think your answer works. I came up with `regex = /([^@]*)(@.*?@)?/` with `text.gsub(regex){"#{$1.upcase}#{$2}"}` which also seems to work. Not sure which is better.

Comment: Your solution may be cleaner. Good Regex too, and I should have thought about that.

Comment: I have followed up this question with another question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73294327/follow-up-to-ruby-regex-replace-text-except-text-inside-delimiter)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to uppercase the left and right side after the @ chars:

```
([^\s@]+)((?:@[^\s@]+)*@)([^\s@]+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `([^\s@]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars other than @ or a whitespace char
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:@[^\s@]+)*@` Optionally repeat matching @ followed by 1+ chars other than @, and then match at least a single @
- `)` Close group 2
- `([^\s@]+)` Capture **group 3**, match 1+ chars other than @ or a whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XBW5fD/1) | [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/7kjYcr)

```
regex = /([^\s@]+)((?:@[^\s@]+)*@)([^\s@]+)/
text = "aaa@xxx@bbb aaa@xxx@bbb aaa@bbb aaa@xxx@xxx@xxx@bbb"

puts(text.gsub(regex){"#{$1.upcase}#{$2}#{$3.upcase}"})
```

Output

```
AAA@xxx@BBB AAA@xxx@BBB AAA@BBB AAA@xxx@xxx@xxx@BBB
```

If you als want to match whitespace chars and newlines in between:

```
([^@]+)((?:@[^@]+)*@)([^@]+)
```

Comment: Do you mean `text = "aaa@xxx@bbb aaa@xxx@bbb aaa@bbb aaa@xxx@xxx@xxx@bbb"`?

Comment: @Starscream512 Ow yes of course :-) Copy pasting mistake.

Comment: In that case, desired output would be `AAA@xxx@BBB AAA@xxx@BBB AAA@bbb aaa@XXX@xxx@XXX@BBB` because the final `xxx@bbb` is unbalanced therefore not delimited. Also, whitespace should not count as a delimiter.

Comment: @Starscream512 It would be better if you update your question with some more   examples what should be matched and how the replacement should look like. Why should `aaa@bbb` become `AAA@bbb` ? What do you mean by `balanced`? Between 2 @ chars?

Comment: Because `aaa@bbb` is actually `bbb aaa@bbb aaa@xxx`. Balanced means an even number of `@`.

Comment: If `text = "aaa@xxx@bbb aaa@xxx@bbb aaa@bbb aaa@xxx@xxx@xxx@bbb"`, then the first group of `xxx` is inside the delimiters therefore is not effected by `upcase`. The second group of `xxx` is also delimited. Then the next delimited group is the 3rd group of `bbb aaa`, then finally the last delimited group is the `xxx` right before the final `xxx@bbb`. Anything outside the delimiters gets `upcase`ed, everything inside the delimiters stays as is.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "aaa@xxx@bbb aaa@xxx@bbb"
```

```
rgx = /@.*?@|([^@]+)/
```

```
str.gsub(rgx) { |s| $1 ? s.upcase : s }
  #=> "AAA@xxx@BBB AAA@xxx@BBB"
```

The regular expression first attempts to match `@.*?@` (equivalent to `@[^@]*@` assuming the string does not contain newlines). If there is a match it will be held by the block variable `s`. As the match is not captured `$1 #=> nil`, so the match is replaced by itself.

If there is no match of `@.*?@` an attempt is made to match `([^@]+)`. If there is a match, it is captured to group 1, so `$1` in the block will hold a string (a truthy value), causing the match to be replaced with `s.upcase` (same as `$1.upcase`).

I have assumed that the string contains an even number of `@`'s, as the question does not say what is to be done if there are an odd number of `@`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Does this resolve your question? If `@` is the separator, then IMHO, splitting and uppercasing if even index in array would print the expected outcome.

```rb
text = "aaa@xxx@bbb aaa@xxx@bbb"
sArray = text.split(/@/)

finalText = ""

# for loop on sArray with index
sArray.each_with_index do |s, i|
    # if index is odd
    if i.even?
        finalText += s.upcase
    else
        finalText += s.downcase
    end
end

puts finalText
# AAAxxxBBB AAAxxxBBB
```

Comment: No, I would like it done with a single gsub.

Comment: IMHO, we would not know how many matches will be for a given text as there can be variable number of `@` in the string. So addressing matches like `$1`, `$2` will not get us to the complete answer.