# Follow-up to: Ruby regex replace text, except text inside delimiter

Tags: regex, ruby

As a follow-up to [Ruby regex replace text, except text inside delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73258879/ruby-regex-replace-text-except-text-inside-delimiter), I have the following regex, which when used with Ruby's `gsub`, will convert anything not delimited by `@` to uppercase and leave anything inside the delimiter as is:

```
regex = /([^@]*)(@.*?@)?/
text = "aaa@xxx@bbb aaa@xxx@bbb"
text.gsub(regex){"#{$1.upcase}#{$2}"}
AAA@xxx@BBB AAA@xxx@BBB
```

I would like now to change this delimiter to `<span></span>` or some other HTML tag. In other words, the delimiter will become multi-character, and the left and right sides will not be exactly the same.

Comment: You were given the answer on that other question, together with a thorough explanation of how it works. We are not here to write *every* line of code for you. Can you take the explanation on your previous question and figure out which parts need to be changed? It's not a big change

Comment: I would like to use not the answer that was given, but my modified answer. Also, negation only works for single characters.

Comment: Use `text.gsub(/((?:(?!<\/?span>).)*)(<span>.*?<\/span>)?/m){"#{$1.upcase}#{$2}"}` ([demo](https://ideone.com/MJyBHz))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I wasn't familiar with negative lookahead. Why do I usually see it used with a non-capture?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo What's not a big change? The answer seems like a *very significant* change to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```rb
text.gsub(/((?:(?!<\/?span>).)*)(<span>.*?<\/span>)?/m){"#{$1.upcase}#{$2}"}
```

See [the online demo](https://ideone.com/MJyBHz).

*Details*:

- `((?:(?!<\/?span>).)*)` - Group #1: any single char, zero or more but as many as possible occurrences, that does not start `<span>` or `</span>` char sequences
- `(<span>.*?<\/span>)?` - an optional capturing group #2: `<span>`, then any zero or more but as few as possible chars, `</span>`